# How to find unix eth port link speed

Tags: unix, ethernet, openwrt, network-speed

I have small issue with my openwrt router.
I want to know link-speed in format 10M,100M, 1000M, etc.  or 10BaseT .. 
but I can't find it in /proc  or with "ip" command also "dmesg" doesn't provide this data.

Have you any ideas where can I find it? If data be in Hex format it's enough  for me.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you also check `/var/log/dmesg`?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `ethtool` command

http://linux.die.net/man/8/ethtool

EDIT:

You need to check the 'Speed' section. Check below:

```
root ~ ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                            1000baseT/Full
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                            1000baseT/Full
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 100Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 1
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: off (auto)
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: g
    Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                   drv probe link
    Link detected: yes
```

As you can see, my card supports 10/100/1000 however, the 'Speed' section shows the speed it is currently running at:

`Speed: 100Mb/s`

Comment: thanks for answer, I haven't got ethtool in my openwrt router... is there any solution?

Comment: yes, of course,  but I want to find out working speed, NO HW speed,

Comment: I've edited my answer to clarify.

Comment: Yes, that would be great, but I havent got this ethtool, So,  Can you tell me from where ettoll reads this data?  I mean some file in /proc or somthing like this. is it possibel? :) thanks much

Comment: @sjwrong google is your friend - seriously https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=openwrt+install+package and https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=openwrt+install+ethtool

Comment: @lain :) I know how to install package to owrt/ also how to compile whole Firmware, but I need to do it without any tool. Only read it from somewhere and that's all. Reason why I cannot install any package is, I have very small flash , and these tools is too big for me

Answer (score 1):

After few hours of reading /proc/* files I have found solution.
chipset: ar8113

> ```
> "cat /proc/ar8113/port_status"
> ```

and output is:

> LinkUp | NWay Mode Enabled
>           RXPause Enabled | TXPause Enabled
>           Duplex Enabled | Speed 100M